# Drupal custom payment module form problem

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-commerce, drupal-9

I'm a bit new to drupal and i'm trying to create custom payment gateway module and stuck with a problem.
When creating OnSitePaymentGateway, everything is ok and i can edit checkout form with PaymentMethodAddForm. But for OffsitePaymentGatewayBase, I'm unable to output additional information to checkout form.
Here's code details:

```
/**
 * Provides the Cresh payment gateway.
 *
 * @CommercePaymentGateway(
 *   id = "creshio",
 *   label = "Cresh.io",
 *   display_label = "Cresh.io",
 *    forms = {
 *     "offsite-payment" = "Drupal\commerce_creshio\PluginForm\CreshioForm",
 *   },
 *
 *   js_library = "commerce_creshio/creshlib",
 * )
 */
class Creshio extends OffsitePaymentGatewayBase { .... }
```

Then I created CreshioForm.php in src/PluginForm/ and added following:

```
class CreshioForm extends BasePaymentOffsiteForm {
     public function buildConfigurationForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
         $form = parent::buildConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);
         $form['#wrapper_id'] = Html::getUniqueId('payment-add-form-wrapper');
         $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="cresh-placeholder">';
         $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
         return $form;
     }
}
```

And i can't see cresh-placeholder in the form

Comment: May not be the underlying issue, but do you mean to close the div tag in #prefix?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that was a mistake, yes. But, unfortunately, its not fixing this issue :(

Comment: You mean to wrap the entire form in a div having your uniqueID?

Comment: @HarishST yes, and i just want to add additiional content to form for this specific payment gateway

Comment: Why not use custom template for that particular form. In this way, you can wrap the form with additional div and print the form fields inside that.

Comment: @HarishST You mean twig template? I also need to add additional js file and input files and send them to payment gateway via this module. Can i do that with custom template?

Comment: Yes, Twig template. You can attach library to the form which can include js or css files.

Comment: Do you really meant to use buildConfigurationForm() ? or is it buildForm() ?

Comment: @HarishST both are not working. I think the problem is in the PluginForm file, seems like module can't see it.

Comment: @RomanSelin Have you completed this? Or still stuck ?

Comment: What does it return ?